# How to turn off "output to file" in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, psql

The directive

```
\o <output_file>
```

sends subsequent outputs to the specified file.  How can this be disabled - i.e. resume sending output to the terminal session instead of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

give it another `\o` with no argument.

Comment: ah ok! i think I had figured that out in the past .. but did not have confidence to try that now.

Comment: The help doesn't mention that either, it only says how to enable file output.

Comment: you got your award absolutely as soon as possible (i was robo-clicking the ch eck-mark ;) )